# Static member function semantics when calling virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose that we have a class

```
class Abstract {
    Abstract( void );
    virtual ~Abstract( void ) = 0;

    virtual void VirtualFunction( void ) = 0;

    static void CallsVirtual( void ) {
        VirtualFunction();
    }
};
class Concrete : public Abstract {
    Concrete( void ) {}
    ~Concrete( void ){}
    virtual void VirtualFunction( void ) {/* Do virtual function-y stuff */}
};

int main( void ) {
    Concrete _concrete;
    Abstract& _abstractReference = _concrete;

    _abstractReference.callsvirtual();
}
```

Which virtual member function is invoked when a base class static member function is called through a base class pointer to a derived class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. You'll get a compiler error. You can't call non-`static` methods or access non-`static` members from a `static` method.

```
//...
virtual void VirtualFunction( void ) = 0;

static void CallsVirtual( void ) {
    VirtualFunction();   // Nope!
}
//...
```

Comment: this is what i expected since static members functions dont have a this pointer

Comment: You can access non-static members in a static function.  But you'll need an explicit object to do so.

Comment: so if CallsVirtual took a base class pointer as an argument i guess i could circumvent it e.g. CallsVirtual( Abstract& that ) { that.VirtualFunction; } but that takes away from making it static in the first place =)

Answer (score 0):

A non-static member function is invoked by using the `this` pointer. The `this` pointer is implicitly passed to each of the member functions.
However, for `static` member functions the `this` pointer is not passed at all.Hence you cannot call a non-static member function through a static member function.